# dojo.dnd one item at a time only

Tags: dojo, drag-and-drop

Using dojo.dnd, I want to allow a user to drag **only one item at a time**, rather than any arbitrary number, as per the dojo's default behaviour.

At the moment, a user can hold Ctrl and click multiple draggable items at a time, then drag them all as a group. I want to disable this so that the user can only drag one item at any given time.

I'm using a dojo.dnd.Source(), as below.

```
new dojo.dnd.Source(containerNode)
```

...which makes all of the child nodes of containerNode draggable.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to set "singular" property of your dojo.dnd.Source (which is inherited from dojo.dnd.Selector):

```
        new dojo.dnd.Source(containerNode, { singular: true } );
```

Comment: Simple as that... Thanks very much.